# Entity framework core получение данных из нескольких таблиц

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, entity-framework-core

Имеются справочники и из каждого необходимо получить данные. API даёт название таблиц которые должны вернуть данные, но для выбора справочников приходится использовать `if`/`case`.

Код приведённый ниже работает, но вопрос в том, возможно есть более оптимальное решение?

Entity Framework Core только изучаю, в этом моменте ничего лучше придумать не получилось.

```cs
using(DBContext db = new())
{
    List<object> data = new();

    foreach(string title in titles)
    {
        if (title == "Directory1")
        {
            var directory1 = db.Directory1.Include(c => c.Translation);
            data.Add(directory1);
        }

        if (title == "Directory2")
        {
            var directory2 = db.Directory2.Include(c => c.Translation);
            data.Add(directory2);
        }

        if (title == "Directory3")
        {
            var directory3 = db.Directory3.Include(c => c.Translation);
            data.Add(directory3);
        }

        // ...

        if (title == "Directory9")
        {
            var directory9 = db.Directory9.Include(c => c.Translation);
            data.Add(directory9);
        }
    }

    string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data, Formatting.Indented);

    return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status200OK, json);
}
```

Comment: EF и EF **Core** - это два разных фреймворка, отличающихся по своим возможностям. Укажите **точную** версию, которую используете.

Comment: Типы в таблицах `Directory*` разные или одинаковые?

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov EF Core. Directory хранят в себе только айди, для получение информации из таблицы Translation.

Comment: Попробуйте `db.Set<Directory>(title)`

Comment: DBContext покажите, не видно, с чем этот код работает. Если свойства однотипные, то почему `List<object>`? Структуру БД обьясните и суть задачи. Странный код вероятно вызван ошибкой проектирования. Вместо втыкания костылей в этот код лучше бы разобраться с источником проблемы.